# Decrypt Basic authentication token from query param in PHP GET method

Tags: php, basic-authentication, php-7, php-7.2, auth-token

I would like to decrypt the Username and Password which was encrypted using basic authentication.

In my client application I'm having a list of files. if the user wants to download, they will click the anchor link which points to a PHP file with param `id` (i.e., `fileId`) and `token`.

I having a client side anchor tag like

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/management/download.php?id=1&token=YmFsYTphYWFhYWFhYWFh">
    download
</a>
```

The token was created using the following javascript code

```
const token = window.btoa(username + ':' + password)
```

**File: download.php**

```
$fileId = $_GET['id'];
$token = $_GET['token'];

$filePath = getFileById($fileId);

if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filePath).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
    readfile($filePath);
    exit;
}
```

I tried to get the Username and Password from the default `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` but I failed to get the information.

Kindly assist me how to decrypt the Username and Password from the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [base64_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) in PHP to get the username and password separated by `:`.

```
<?php

$decoded = base64_decode($_GET['token']);
list($username,$password) = explode(":",$decoded);
echo $username," ",$password;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/KKIlR

Also, this doesn't seem to be secure enough to send a password(not sure what password depicts here) as is in the GET parameter. It's better to instead send a header like `Authorization: Basic YmFsYTphYWFhYWFhYWFh` where it's actually some client ID and client secret base-64 encoded.

Comment: Yeah, its a very very less secured way but something is better than nothing that's the idea. In the API calls we are using header authentication.

Comment: I up voted for your effort and once tested I'll mark your answer as correct.